# How to deal with default paddings while customise navigation bar with title view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to customise the navigation bar with title view.
But it seems setting title view comes with its own left and right and top paddings.I was expecting the title view to cover the whole navigation bar according to the frames given.

Is it expected behaviour and if YES than how to deal with that?

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 44)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    //Navigation Bar
    self.navigationItem.titleView = view;
```

[image: The Navigation Title View is in green]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the navigation bar to be green use `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];` in iOS 7+ or `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];` in iOS 6-

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems it is not possible to remove that left/right padding. This is the screenshot form debugging views in Xcode after running your code

[image]

The outside view that is gray is the `navigationBar` and the green is obviously the `titleView`. No matter the frame for the `titleView`, it is clipped.

Apple documentation says just this:

**Custom title views are centered on the navigation bar and may be resized to fit.**

I think the only solution would be to subclass the `navigationBar`, so that you override the titleView frame.